# How to change mat-select model after changing the object?

Tags: angular

I have the following code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let h of headers; let index = index">
            <td>
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-select [ngModel]="h" placeholder="Select type" (selectionChange)="selectType($event, h, index)">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let h of headers" [value]="h">{{h}}</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
    </tr>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let row of rows">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let h of headers">
                {{row[h]?.value || ''}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

How to change `[ngModel]="h"` on value that was changed in `row[h]`?
So if `row["name"]`  comes to `row["age"]` the `[ngModel]="h"` should be 'age'.

Where `headers` is: `["age", "name"];`
The `rows` is: `[{"name": "Oleg"}, {"age": 17}]`

Comment: You should create a stackblitz to demonstrate the issue.